# What is the best practice when creating many ActiveRecord objects in one POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In our rails 5.2.3 and ruby 2.6.0 app we're developing a booking system where users can post what times & dates they're available. One of the requested features is that users can put in a period of dates, in other words a start and end date. My question is what the best practice would be to create the ActiveRecord objects for all of those dates. Currently i have this part of the whole solution as i decided to get some input/feedback before i take it further.

```rb
#ShiftController 

def create
  start = DateTime.parse(shift_params)
  stop = DateTime.parse(shift_params)

  days_between = (start.to_date..stop.to_date).count
  shifts_to_save = []

  days_between.times do |i|
    stop_time = stop - days_between + i
    shift = Shift.new(food: params[:shift][:food], start_time: start, end_time: stop_time)
    shifts_to_save.push shift
    current_user.shifts << shift
  end
end
```

If i add a snippet which iterates over the `shifts_to_save` array and save each entry, and then showing errors once all shifts have been iterated over i think it would work as intended. But the solution doesn't make me proud nor does it feel like ruby on rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap creation of multiple records in a database transaction. This will be faster and ensures that all records are either created together or not created, eg:

```
Shift.transaction do
  # create shifts inside here using save! or create! to ensure rollback upon failure
end
```

However, stuffing the above logic into a transaction just feels like a large chunk of procedural code. It would probably be more Rails-y to identify the domain concepts involved and move them into the model layer for easier understanding and standalone unit testing, eg:

```
#ShiftController 

def create
  start = DateTime.parse(shift_params)
  stop = DateTime.parse(shift_params)

  Shift.indicate_availability(
    user: current_user,
    start: start,
    stop: stop,
    food: params[:food]
  )
end
```

Comment: can also raise certain errors if you want and add to the model's error class :D

Comment: I ended up opting for your solution with moving it into the model layer, tidied up the code quite a bit and makes it easier to manage, cheers!